# How to choose fscanf format based on the type of the variable?

Tags: c

Let's say I'm implementing a matrix and I want my struct to use `scalar_t`, where `scalar_t` can be `float` or `double`.

Then, let's say I want to scan some text file and load it into my matrix:

```
// Inner loop:
fscanf(mdata, format, &m->data[i * m->cols + j]);
```

If `scalar_t *` is `float *`, `format` should be `"%f"`. In case of `double *` it's `"%lf"`.

How do I condition the format on the type of `scalar_t`? I know that I could compare `sizeof` but is there a general solution?

Comment: Perhaps use [*generic selection*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)?

Comment: scalar_t is an union ? So you have "full control" wether scalart_t is a float or double ? So you can choose which format to use with your fscanf.

Comment: I think you could always use `%lf`, or if nothing comes to your mind you could always read number to double tmp variable, and then assign it to `&m->data[i * m->cols + j]`

Comment: @stetoc The first part of your comment is quite wrong, I'm afraid.  If `m->data` is an array of float, then `fscanf(mdata, "%lf", &m->data[i * m->cols + j]);` will *not* work.  (The scanf functions are totally not like printf in this regard.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The designers of C99's `<inttypes.h>` had a similar problem. They defined types like `int32_t` with some specific properties, and allowed each implementation to typedef it as `int` or `long` as necessary. But then printf and scanf formats became platform-specific.

Their solution was to define a set of macros along with each type, like `SCNd32` which will be `"d"` or `"ld"` to match `int` or `long` for the typedef.

Usage looks like

```
int32_t i;
scanf("%"SCNd32, &i);
```

For each type, there's a separate macro for every conversion that you might want to do with the type (so not just `d` but also `x` for hex, etc.)

You can do the same for your custom types. In the header:

```
#if something
typedef float scalar_t;
#define SCNfSCALAR "f"
#else
typedef double scalar_t;
#define SCNfSCALAR "lf"
#endif
```

And in the calling code:

```
scalar_t x;
scanf("%"SCNfSCALAR, &x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that

1. You are going to need a `union` that has a `float` and a `double`.
2. The C standard requires a `double` to be a superset of a `float`.
3. Increasingly, platforms are setting `float` and `double` to the same thing, although they are required to be separate types, much along the lines of `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` are always three separate types.

by far the best thing to do here is to use a `double`.

Comment: I have _never_ heard of a platform on which `float` and `double` had the same representation.  That seems like the sort of thing that might have happened on the original Cray, not the sort of thing that anyone would do now. Can you give specific examples, please?

Comment: @zwol: I have it on reasonable good authority that this machine does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Simulator. Although despite my best intentions, nobody is ever going to let me near that thing!